# ionic framework / ionic native http: ssl client based authentification

Tags: ssl, ionic-framework, https, ionic-native, mutual-authentication

im refering to this issue: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-native-http-ssl-client-based-authentification/129596

any ideas how to implement ssl client based authentification (mutual tls) within the ionic framework? im using the ionic native http plugin. i placed the .cer file within the platforms/android/asset folder.

```
this.http.acceptAllCerts(true);
this.http.enableSSLPinning(false);

this.http.get('https://someip/backend/all', {}, {})
  .then(data => {
    console.log("data",data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("error",error);
  });
```

currently the http requests are not sending the required ssl certificate with each request.

```
<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

same issue when using angular/http to send the http requests

ionic info

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 5.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v6.11.3
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\myname\Android\sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: You need to add some more informatoin please use `ionic info` => which platform you want to use ?

Comment: i added the requested ionic info output, im trying to build an android apk which uses cliented based ssl authentification. the issue is how to send http request containing the my certificate (format .p12 or something else)

Answer (score 1):

For Android, I use Cordova with the plugin "cordova-client-cert-authentication" installed, this worked straight away: After installing the plugin and compiling the app, it asks for which certificate to use as soon as the app is started and the requests work as expected.

This does require you to install the certificate in your phone's identity storage though, which forces you to enable a lock-screen on your device.

Comment: i can confirm this, the issue got solved using the cordova-client-cert-authentication plugin